# Is my app size normal?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, size

I created an iPhone app and after archiving it, adding it to iTunes, showing it in the Finder, I got the ipa file that is 23.9 MBs in size. I un-archived it using The Unarchiver and got the Payload folder. Inside it, along other files, i got a 7.1 MB Assets.car file, a 9.5 MB exec file (project's name) and a 40.1 MB Frameworks folder. I used different softwares to compress my PNGs (ImgOptim, ImgAlpha, TinyPNG), and I also tried changing COMPRESS_PNG_FILES to no, but it didn't affect the size

Is this normal? I used import UIKit, Foundation and AVFoundation inside my classes. (currently using Xcode 7 Beta 3, waiting for the GM download to finish)

**EDIT :** I'm going to add the StartApp SDK for ads later on. Will the size increase a lot? And do you recommend StartApp or other websites to display ads on the app with a high revenue for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes 23.9 MB is pretty normal for a barebones app. I've worked on an app recently which had 100+ images and a few videos which turned into a 500+MB ipa file.

So 23.9 MB is pretty normal.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to add the StartApp SDK for ads later on. Will the size increase a lot ? And do you recommend StartApp or other websites to display ads on the app with a high revenue for me ?

Comment: I've never used StartApp SDK before, but I doubt it will. I mainly use Chartboost for ad revenue for my apps:http://apple.co/1Dol8Ao, but high revenue will highly depend on your marketing effect.

Comment: Do you consider your revenue high enough, for one app at least ? Like more than 150$ per year ? If so, by how much ? (if you don't mind me asking)

Comment: I don't mind talking about revenue, but out of all my apps this one is only making money:http://apple.co/1L4M00I. I release it, I believe, two weeks ago and it made 50$ total, but that's only with ASO and no marketing effect. So 150$ by the end of the year is doable. The rest of my apps only made penney :(. I do plan, in a few week, to start a marketing plan so i can push those numbers up.

Comment: Ohh. Good luck! How many people downloaded "Avoid The Red Dots" app   so far ?

Comment: As of now 160 downloads.

Comment: Oh that's great. 160 downloads -> 50$ . Oh the number became 161 (or even more) :D

Comment: Not yet. This is my first app. When i do i'll post it here. But my app is focused on card games played in the arab region, like Lebanon where i'm from, so i don't think you'll be interested in it.

Comment: First app is always the hardest. Good luck on its' success. Shot me an email when it's live. randel.smith34@gmail.com. I'll give it a play and send it around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal. I have worked on multiple apps with ipa's > 30MB.

Comment: Thanks. Check the EDIT part please

Comment: I don't think this will have a large impact. That SDK sits somewhere around 20MB. However, I personally do not have any experience with that framework so I can't reccomend alternatives.